# Integrating Restricted Neo4j Bloom Functionality into React.js Application

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-visualization, neo4j-bloom

I aim to integrate Neo4j Bloom into a React.js application using an iframe. This integration will allow users of the React application to interact with and navigate through the graph. However, I intend to provide limited access to the user, specifically restricting access to options like perspectives, nodes, and relationships. The user should only have access to the search tab and the canvas view, similar to what is visible in presentation mode. How can I implement these access restrictions in Neo4j Bloom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to integrate Neo4j Bloom as iFrame in your application and customise the behavior using [deep link](https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/bloom-tutorial/deep-links/).

Deep links are query string parameters that allow you to fill the search box or run a search showing the subhgraph you're looking for. See the link above for more information.

Unfortunately it is not possible to limit the capabilities of the UI programmatically.

Is possible to limit some operations, like creating new nodes or deleting and modifying the properties of nodes from Bloom if you give read only capabilities to the user you use when login into Bloom (for example giving the "reader" role to the users).

In order to do this I suggest you take a look at the neo4j documentation, like [Tutorial in fine grained access control](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/access-control/)
and [managing privileges](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/manage-privileges/)

Just for completeness, it is not possible to pass the credentials programmatically using querystring parameters for security reasons.

If you have Enterprise version of Bloom might be other way to restrict the access to capabilities but then I'll invite you to check out our [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/bloom-perspectives/perspective-rbac/)